# How can I share a Sage Interaction on a website without giving away the code?

Tags: html, sage

I would like to add numerical examples coded in Sage (e.g. https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/) to my website without making available the code in the html.

Comment: For reference: this question also asked at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35526/how-can-i-share-a-sage-interaction-on-a-website-without-giving-away-the-code/